# Problema na criação de layout fixo

Tags: html, css, layout

Galera, estou com problemas pra criar um `layout` fixo que se adapte somente à altura ou largura da tela, seja do celular ou desktop. Mas não é um site responsivo, é um site normal para `desktop`, não pra versão `mobile`, porém quando eu abro aqui no meu celular fica umas partes fora do layout ou embaixo do `rodape`, não consigo encontrar onde estou errando.

Esse é o site:

http://www.iracemafilha.com.br

Acho que o problema está na configuração do body ou da div "tudo" ou até mesmo em alguma div que está passando da tela e por isso está grande e não se adaptando.

Aqui está o site no repositório, se alguém quiser dar uma olhada no que está acontecendo.

https://github.com/isckosta/IracemaFilhaV2.git

Comment: Não é por causa dos `min-width` e `min-height`?

Comment: Já tentei sem eles usando só o width: 100%; mas continua feio.

Comment: Se você quer algo bonito ai você quer site `responsivo` sim.

Comment: Não, você não entendeu. Existem sites que não são responsivos, você abre ele no celular e ele continua normal, do jeito que fica na tela do computador.

Comment: No meu celular só fica zuado a parte do footer estar com `min-width: 1353px` enquanto o body está com `min-width: 768px`. Se você deixar o body com `1353px` fica normal.

Comment: Que topo? De qual div você está se referindo?

Comment: É o body no seu CSS

Comment: Retirar o min width do footer e colocar no body?

Comment: Não, manter os 2 iguais com `min-width: 1353px`

Comment: E quanto a altura? Tenta dar um zoom.

Comment: Olha aí ficou melhor agora, porém tá com uma tarja branca em baixo do rodapé.

Comment: Pra resolver isso do espaço em branco tu vai ter que usar http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Tente ver o [960gs](http://960.gs/), ele é muito bom para site não responsivo, a versão do desktop vai ser a mesmo do mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Cara dei uma olhada no código super rápido, a diagramação tá meio estranha.Mas tá fácil de resolver trabalha com wrapper (100%) defina com container-fixed dentro de cada sections com tamanho da resolução que vc quer atender ex: 960px.

O correto seria trabalhar com medidas relativas e criação de breakpoints com mediaqueries. Mas o start dentro do que vc quer é isso.

Dá uma olhada no básico pra vc ter um idéia:
http://codepen.io/carlos-jcdesign/pen/RPyeoZ

Answer (score 0):

Uma estratégia que você pode usar neste caso é corrigir dinamicamente a altura e a largura da página para que elas sejam sempre iguais à altura e largura da tela do dispositivo, respectivamente.

Para isso, coloque o código a seguir dentro do bloco `<script type="text/javascript">` no arquivo **index.php**:

```
var corrigirTamanhoDaPagina = function() {
    // Ajusta a largura da página para ficar igual à largura 
    // da tela do dispositivo (celular, tablet ou pc).
    $("body").css("width", $(document).width() + "px");

    // Ajusta a altura da página para ficar igual à altura da tela do dispositivo.
    $("#div-content").css("height", $(document).height() + "px");
};

// Irá corrigir o tamanho da página assim que ela for carregada.
$(document).ready(function() {
    corrigirTamanhoDaPagina();
});

// Faz com que o tamanho da página seja corrigido sempre que a tela mudar de tamanho, 
// por exemplo quando o celular muda do modo paisagem para retrato e vice versa.
$(window).resize(function() {
    corrigirTamanhoDaPagina(); 
});
```

Comment: Concordo com a lógica, porém não com a aplicação (método). O Progressive Enhancement sempre em primeiro lugar certo! Sendo assim porque ser dinâmico  se posso fazer o mesmo com css, afinal quero ter certeza que o conteúdo vai ser entregue de acordo e não posso jogar essa responsa pro javascript. Enfim usaria a mesma lógica do seu script apenas com 2 ou no máximo 3 linhas de breakpoints css (media query).

Comment: @carlosjcdesign sim. No caso essa não é bem uma solução, e sim um workaround. Funcionar funciona, apesar de não ser a solução ideal. E caso não seja encontrada a solução ideal, essa não deixa de ser uma alternativa.